# Trouble Saving a XML in the Format Expected with Foreach C#

Tags: c#, foreach, console-application

I have a problem saving a XML File in the format I’m looking for
Maybe someone can help me out here is my code

```
string testInput= @"<!LinkName>MyChildData<#";
var testRegex = new Regex(@"(?<name>(?<=<!).*?(?=>))|(?<namex>(?<=>).*?(?=<#))",
                          RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);

foreach (Match myMatch in testRegex.Matches(testInput))
{                     
    xml.NewChild2(myMatch.Groups["name"].Value, myMatch.Groups["namex"].Value);
}
xml.SaveXml("simple.xml");
```

Result I’m expecting
Is

```
<rootNode>
    <LinkName>MyChildData</LinkName>
</rootNode>
```

But the result I get is

```
<rootNode>
    <LinkName/> 
    <nothing>MyChildData</nothing>
</rootNode>
```

Any Advise would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: what is this mysterious `xml` object?  is it an `XmlDocument`? or an `XDocument` maybe?  `NewChild2` looks like a bizzare name for a built in type... is it a user-defined type?

Comment: Why are you doing this?  There are these things called Schemas which are really nice.  Please research XSD

Comment: Need more Input: Specifically, where is the `testInput` coming from, what format will it be in, etc etc.  What is `xml`, there could be better ways to generate what you are looking for.  At the moment, I would say that the error is more likely to be in the Regex than in the foreach loop.  Looks like you are ending up with the node name separate from the node data in the foreach loop, which is a result of the Regex

Comment: @ Dan Andrews  ---  Im doing this so that i don't have to define a schema but generate it on the fly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the Regex, when I run the current string I get two DIFFERENT match sets.  One where Name is LinkName, but namex is empty, and one where name is empty, but namex is correct.

try using this regex instead:

```
(?<name>(?<=<!).*?)>(?<namex>.*?(?=<#))
```

note how instead of using options, the `|` character, instead I link the two together, ignoring the `>` character.  This way it guarantees that the structure has to be `name>value`.

If you cannot guarantee that structure, then you need to rethink the entire process.

Comment: Dude you are Awesome that sorted the problem !!!! it works as i expected it to thanks!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: i noticed the issue with the regex but wassnt sure that was the issue and could not get it sorted but so you learn every day Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You are adding your node to the xml, not to `<LinkName>`.  Look up `AddChild()`